# POST method not allowed Web Api

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, http

I created a web api for an android application.But POST method not allowed.I tried all of the solutions and non of them worked.I added these lines in Web.config,but error is still same.

```
 <handlers><remove name="WebDAV"/></handlers>                         
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"                     
 <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>                                       
</modules>
```

Also Cors is enabled and

```
 <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
```

is done.My controller is,

```
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAuth([FromBody] Credential userInfo)
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(connStr);

        try
        {
            var userDetail = dc.users.FirstOrDefault(f => f.userName == userInfo.UserName && f.userPassword == userInfo.UserPassword);
            if (userDetail == null)
            {
                return Json(new AuthResult { ErrorCode = 0 });
            }
            else
                return Json(new AuthResult { ErrorCode = 1 });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                return Json(new AuthResult { ErrorCode = -1 });
        }

    }
```

My URL is http:/(ip address)/api/Data/GetAuth/.I'm listening on Postman and Header shows that

> Allow →GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE

Thank you...

Comment: Change the method name to just Auth without the Get.

Comment: Is the missing angle bracket in your config really missing in your project? (`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"       `)

Comment: @CathalMF, or even better `PostAuth`

Comment: @CathalMF I tried now but didn't work.

Comment: are you able to get to any resources on the API? are you sure that  http://api is going to your test environment and not somewhere else when being called from the android (e.g. local machine uses host file while android used DNS that points to a different environment)? What are the routes and are they correct? If so, can you get into a similar GET method in the same controller?

Comment: @Jamiec not missing in project and PostAuth also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your route config?

Comment: I added Route and it works ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @lyd can you show the Route in WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: @umasankar Actually I described the URL in Local IIS and when I added an empty route like [Route("")],I don't know how but it worked.

Comment: @lyd did it work in the same endpoint you were trying?